# Issue With Oracle 12c Installation

Tags: windows, oracle

I'm running Windows 10 Pro fresh after a computer restore, so it's been factory reset.

I download the Oracle package and extract all the files and run the setup file and the program just quits on its own running the Prerequisite check with no error diaglogues or anything

Log file is too large to attach but I don't see any "FAILURE" and the last few lines of file look like this:

```
*********************************************
INFO: Physical Memory: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the system has at least 1GB (1048576.0KB) of total physical memory.
INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
INFO: OverallStatus:SUCCESSFUL
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: Verification Result for Node:laptop-8gmvgrg9
INFO: Expected Value:1GB (1048576.0KB)
INFO: Actual Value:15.8406GB (1.661008E7KB)
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: *********************************************
INFO: Available Physical Memory: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the system has at least 50MB (51200.0KB) of available physical memory.
INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
INFO: OverallStatus:SUCCESSFUL
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: Verification Result for Node:laptop-8gmvgrg9
INFO: Expected Value:50MB (51200.0KB)
INFO: Actual Value:11.6503GB (1.2216188E7KB)
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: *********************************************
INFO: Swap Size: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether sufficient total swap space is available on the system.
INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
INFO: OverallStatus:SUCCESSFUL
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: Verification Result for Node:laptop-8gmvgrg9
INFO: Expected Value:15.8406GB (1.661008E7KB)
INFO: Actual Value:18.7156GB (1.9624736E7KB)
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: *********************************************
INFO: Free Space: laptop-8gmvgrg9:C:\Users\shopp\AppData\Local\Temp: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether sufficient free space is available in the file system.
INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
INFO: OverallStatus:SUCCESSFUL
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: Verification Result for Node:laptop-8gmvgrg9
INFO: Expected Value:500MB 
INFO: Actual Value:393.6558GB 
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: *********************************************
INFO: Architecture: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the system has a certified architecture.
INFO: Severity:CRITICAL
INFO: OverallStatus:SUCCESSFUL
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: Verification Result for Node:laptop-8gmvgrg9
INFO: Expected Value:64-bit
INFO: Actual Value:64-bit
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
```

I'm generally a Linux user and have no familiarity with Windows -- could anyone help me figure out what my problems are?

Comment: With no known error message and a snippet of the output you are basically asking us to make a lucky guess. Maybe someone will be able to diagnose this. I am going to make an alternate suggestion: virtualisation. Oracle has supported images on [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) for years.  There's a wide range of VMs available on [Oracle TechNet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html). Recently Oracle has embraced Docker and there are now Docker installs on github (licensed and unlicensed - choose wisely!).

Comment: I want to install locally. The entire install file is too large to put in ticket - that’s the reason for the snippet. 

If there is any pertinent information in the log that I need to include I am happy to do that. 

It’s very frustrating having such horrible logging for errors.